# ORA-12514 TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus, ora-12514, tnsping

We have an application running locally where we're experiencing the following error:

> ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested
>   in connect descriptor

I've tested the connection using `TNSPing` which resolved correctly and
I tried `SQLPlus` to try connecting, which failed with the same error as above. I used this syntax for `SQLPlus`:

```
sqlplus username/password@addressname[or host name]
```

We have verified that:

- the TNS Listener on the server is running.
- Oracle itself on the server is running.

We don't know of any changes that were made to this environment. 
Anything else we can test?

Comment: what is TNSPing command (with params) that you used?

Comment: when you say "running locally" you mean that the application is connecting   to a database on the same host? Also, what are the contents of your sqlnet.ora file? what versions are reported for sqlplus and tnsping, and are you sure that they're in the same ORACLE_HOME?

Comment: try restarting the database. Since they supposed to inform the Listener about their existence on startup this might fix your problem.

Comment: ALTER SYSTEM REGISTER is less drastic than restarting the database.

Comment: After researching enough found the right solution here https://shekhargulati.com/2019/01/22/solution-ora-12514-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-service-requested-in-connect-descriptor/

Comment: It is possibly as simple as a typo in the host name or other connection properties (that is what happened to me).  Of course, other comments and  answers are valid and detail more complex situations.

Answer (score 276, accepted):

I had this issue and the fix was to make sure in `tnsnames.ora` the `SERVICE_NAME` is a valid service name in your database. To find out valid service names, you can use the following query in oracle:

```
select value from v$parameter where name='service_names'
```

Once I updated `tnsnames.ora` to:

```
TEST =
   (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = *<validhost>*)(PORT = *<validport>*))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = *<servicenamefromDB>*)
    )
)
```

then I ran:

```
sqlplus user@TEST
```

Success! 
The listener is basically telling you that whatever service_name you are using isn't a valid service according to the DB.

(*I was running sqlplus from Win7 client workstation to remote DB and blame the DBAs ;) *)

Comment: Thanks alot, you solved my problem ;)
But where is the tnsnames.ora located?

Comment: On win7, %ORACLE_HOME%\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora

Comment: How am I supposed to query the DB if I'm not able to even connect to it??

Comment: Can you ssh to the DB server directly and run sqlplus from there?

Comment: this might not be the case when multiple clients/servers are, or used to be, installed on the same machine. (tnsping outputs the location of the directory it uses) - in my case, listener.ora in that directory contained information pertaining to an old database instance that i had uninstalled - quick and dirty way was to copy the entire contents of listener.ora from my current installation of Oracle Express, to that other directory that listener seems to be checking (i think i changed it through a registry or something, and it has precedence over ORACLE_HOME (?))

Comment: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: @isabellemartz https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786782/ora-12514-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-service-requested-in-connect-d/30861690#30861690

Comment: [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PIlY07mvrYA) worked for me after reviewing every single answer

Comment: I am sorry to agree with hello_earth, the rightest answer is listener.ora, although the answer is still useful.

Comment: I found right solution here https://shekhargulati.com/2019/01/22/solution-ora-12514-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-service-requested-in-connect-descriptor

Comment: The Oracle db-query is enormously helpful.  I got a list and one of the items in the list returned worked, the other did not.  Therefore, some trial and error is required.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It work now even after 11 years. Wow. I used it for Oracle XE (21) on Windows 11. Those who want to try out this command(to know the service as most of the DB clients default it to ORCL - it's XE in my case). Open command prompt and run this command "C:\Windows\System32>sqlplus / AS sysdba" and then this command select value from v$parameter where name='service_names' . It should give you the service name.

Answer (score 72):

I know this is an old question, but still unanswered.  It took me a day of research, but I found the simplest solution, at least in my case (Oracle 11.2 on Windows 2008 R2) and wanted to share.

The error, if looked at directly, indicates that the listener does not recognize the service name.  But where does it keep service names?  In `%ORACLE_HOME%\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora`

The "SID_LIST" is just that, a list of SIDs and service names paired up in a format you can copy or lookup.

I added the problem Service Name, then in Windows "Services" control panel, I did a "Restart" on the Oracle listener service.  Now all is well.

---

For example, your listener.ora file might initially look like:

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\oracle_user\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\oracle_user\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\oracle_user\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr12.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

... And to make it recognize a service name of `orcl`, you might change it to:

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\oracle_user\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\oracle_user\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\oracle_user\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr12.dll")
    )
    (SID_DESC = 
        (GLOBAL_DBNAME = orcl)
        (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\oracle_user\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1)
        (SID_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

Comment: Need to update this answer with the syntax of how `listener.ora` stores the names.  I don't even have a `listener.ora` file.  I'm also on a client workstation running SQL Developer and trying to just create a Database Link when I get the error.  I don't have an Oracle Listener service to restart.

Comment: vapcguy, you need to be on the database server. it sounds like you are on the client

Comment: After following Sepideh's instructions involving the Net Manager, I noticed that my listeners.ora file had been updated to contain a new SID_LIST entry. I have edited this answer to include a before-and-after example of the syntax, for the benefit of readers that can't use the Net Manager, for whatever reason.

Answer (score 30):

In my circumstances the error was due to the fact the listener did not have the db's service registered. I solved this by registering the services. Example:

My descriptor in `tnsnames.ora`:

```
LOCALDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = LOCALDB)
    )
  )
```

So, I proceed to register the service in the `listener.ora` manually:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
    (SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = LOCALDB)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (SID_NAME = LOCALDB)
    )
```

Finally, restart the listener by command:

```
> lsnrctl stop
> lsnrctl start
```

Done!

Comment: I made it here, but there was a final block that stated error ORA-01219 (pluggable database not open) that kept me from opening the tables.  They opened when logging into the EE database with the sys/pwd@ipaddress:port.  Untikl then SQL Developer would not allow the tables to open until that account ran "startup;" for that instance.

Answer (score 14):

I had this issue at **Windows server 2008 R2** and **Oracle 11g**

> go to Net Manager > Listener > select database services form the combox > "Global Database Name" must be same as "SID" and "Oracle Home Directory" must be correct.

If you don't have any entry for database services, create one and set correct global database , `sid` and oracle home.

Comment: This was wrong on my system: *"Global Database Name" must be same as "SID"* - this isn't intuitive at all, if these values have to be identical, why are these two separate parameters?? -.-

Answer (score 14):

This really should be a comment to [Brad Rippe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/979521/brad-rippe)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16049014/1757756), but alas, not enough rep. That answer got me 90% of the way there. In my case, the installation and configuration of the databases put entries in the tnsnames.ora file for the databases I was running. First, I was able to connect to the database by setting the environment variables (Windows):

```
set ORACLE_SID=mydatabase
set ORACLE_HOME=C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1
```

and then connecting using

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

Next, running the command from [Brad Rippe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16049014/1757756):

```
select value from v$parameter where name='service_names';
```

showed that the names didn't match exactly. The entries as created using Oracle's Database Configuration Assistant were originally:

```
MYDATABASE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = mylaptop.mydomain.com)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = mydatabase.mydomain.com)
    )
  )
```

The service name from the query was just `mydatabase` rather than `mydatabase.mydomain.com`. I edited the tnsnames.ora file to just the base name without the domain portion so they looked like this:

```
MYDATABASE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = mylaptop.mydomain.com)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = mydatabase)
    )
  )
```

I restarted the TNS Listener service (I often use `lsnrctl stop` and `lsnrctl start` from an administrator command window [or Windows Powershell] instead of the Services control panel, but both work.) After that, I was able to connect.

Comment: Just looking up `SERVICE_NAME` from `tnsnames.ora` and using the value found there in my connection did it for me. I did not have any `SID_LIST_LISTENER` in `listener.ora`, so seems not necessary.

Answer (score 13):

For thoses Who are using spring-boot and jdbc for connection.
You have to be careful while writing jdbcUrl in application.properties

With SID in Database connection - 
           `source.datasource.jdbcUrl = jdbc:oracle:thin:@[HOST][:PORT]:SID`

With Service name in db connection
           `globe.datasource.jdbcUrl = jdbc:oracle:thin:@//[HOST][:PORT]/SERVICE`

This worked for me :)

Answer (score 10):

Starting the **OracleServiceXXX** from the `services.msc` worked for me in Windows.

Comment: In windows, if you are using Oracle Release 12.x, then make sure the service OracleServiceORCL is running. If this service is not started, then also you will receive the same error code.

Answer (score 6):

For Dbeaver users: try selecting "SID" instead of "Service name" in connection settings.

Comment: For me, turned out that SID= instead of Service_Name= in the connect string did the job. Despite having some documentation which tells me to use Service_Name= to specify the SID...well, whatever. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. For me, just writing

```
sqlplus myusername/mypassword@localhost
```

did the trick, doing so makes it connect to the default service name, I guess.

Comment: We had a similar issue with our connection string causing this error.  We were connecting using Oracle's JDBC thin driver with the connection string: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/orcl`.  The corrected connection string to eliminate this error was: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521`.

Comment: it depends whether this would work - i think this way of connecting, judging on what others said, is bypassing the listener entirely, using the computer host name instead of SID - this way of connecting causes problems in third-party clients, - i think it also works only when the EZCONNECT is specified in sqlnet.ora:

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)

Answer (score 4):

This error can occur when an application makes a new connection for every database interaction or the connections are not closed properly. One of the free tools to monitor and confirm this is  Oracle Sql developer (although this is not the only tool you can use to monitor DB sessions).

you can download the tool from oracle site [Sql Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html)

here is a screenshot of how to monitor you sessions. (if you see many sessions piling up for your application user during when you see the ORA-12514 error then it's a good indication that you may have connection pool problem).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Check to see the database is up. Log onto the server, set the ORACLE_SID environment variable to your database SID, and run SQL*Plus as a local connection.

Comment: This was exactly my problem. Our database is hosted on a VM which was down while I was attempting to use another program that used the DP. After seeing this thread I realized it was probably down.

Answer (score 3):

I had also faced the same problem and spent 3 days to dig it out.

This happens because of your wrong TNS service entry.

First check  whether you are able to connect to standby database from  primary database using sql > `sqlplus  sys@orastand as sysdba` (`orastand` is a standby database).

If you are not able to connect then it is a problem with the service. Correct the entry of  service name in TNS file at primary end.

Check standby database the same way. Make the changes here too if required.

Make sure the `log_archive_dest_2` parameter has the correct service name.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this issue in my linux enviroment updating the IP of my machine in /etc/hosts file.

You can verify your network IP (inet end.) with:

```
$ifconfig
```

See if your IP matches with /etc/hosts file:

```
$cat /etc/hosts
```

Edit your /etc/hosts file, if nedded:

```
$sudo gedit /etc/hosts
```

Bye.

Comment: this is old, but it doesn't make much sense to add your IP to /etc/hosts. OP is missing SERVICE_NAME, other stuff is quite unrelated

Comment: I have not added my IP to /etc/host. I just corrected it. As you can see in this topic, there are many valid (with upvote) answers and varieties to solve this question. If that answer did not help you, why downvote? This answer may still help someone as it helped me.

Answer (score 3):

what worked for me was really simple, I just needed to initiate the service manually in the "Windows Services" (services.msc in cmd trompt).
my service name is: OracleServiceXXXXX.

Comment: In my case, though Startup Type is set to Automatic, it does not start when machine is boot. After manually start service "OracleServiceXE", it works for Oracle Database 11g Express to connect to DB and APEX(Oracle Application Express) webpage.

Answer (score 2):

For those that may be running Oracle in a VM (like me) I saw this issue because my VM was running out of memory, which seems to have prevented OracleDB from starting up/running correctly. Increasing my VM memory and restarting fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of answers here, but here comes a working example with code that you can copy and paste and test immediately:

For me the error 12514 was solved after specifying the correct SERVICE_NAME.
You find that on the server in the file `tnsnames.ora` which comes with 3 predefined service names (one of them is "XE").

1. I installed the Oracle Express database OracleXE112 which already comes with some preinstalled demo tables.
2. When you start the installer you are asked for a password. I entered "xxx" as password. (not used in production)
3. My server runs on the machine 192.168.1.158
4. On the server you must explicitely allow access for the process TNSLSNR.exe in the Windows Firewall. This process listens on port 1521.
5. **OPTION A:** For C# (.NET2 or .NET4) you can download **ODAC11**, from which you have to add Oracle.DataAccess.dll to your project. Additionally this DLL depends on: OraOps11w.dll, oci.dll, oraociei11.dll (130MB!), msvcr80.dll. 
   These DLLs must be in the same directory as the EXE or you must specify the DLL path in: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Oracle\ODP.NET\4.112.4.0\DllPath`. On 64 bit machines write additionally to `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Oracle\...`
6. **OPTION B:** If you have downloaded **ODAC12** you need Oracle.DataAccess.dll, OraOps12w.dll, oci.dll, oraociei12.dll (160MB!), oraons.dll, msvcr100.dll. The Registry path is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Oracle\ODP.NET\4.121.2.0\DllPath`
7. **OPTION C:** If you don't want huge DLL's of more than 100 MB you should download ODP.NET_Managed12.x.x.x.xxxxx.zip in which you find `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll` which is only 4 MB and is a pure managed DLL which works in 32 bit and 64 bit processes as well and depends on no other DLL and does not require any registry entries.
8. The following C# code works for me without any configuration on the server side (just the default installation):

```
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
or
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;

....

string oradb = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION="
    + "(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.1.158)(PORT=1521)))"
    + "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=XE)));"
    + "User Id=SYSTEM;Password=xxx;";

using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb)) 
{
    conn.Open();
    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection  = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "select TABLESPACE_NAME from DBA_DATA_FILES";

        using (OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                listBox.Items.Add(dr["TABLESPACE_NAME"]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the `SERVICE_NAME=XE` is wrong you get error 12514. The `SERVICE_NAME` is optional. You can also leave it away.

Comment: Thanks a lot, from your solution I found the trick, in my case, it was the anti-virus that was blocking the program, hence was not able to obtain a connection to the Oracle db.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the database had ran out of disk space.   Which caused it to not respond.   Once I cleared up that issue everything worked again.

Comment: How can I find this out?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error because the remote SID specified was wrong:

```
 > sqlplus $DATASOURCE_USERNAME/$DATASOURCE_PASSWORD@$DB_SERVER_URL/$REMOTE_SID
```

I queried the system database:

select * from global_name;

and found my remote SID ("XE").

Then I could connect without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, round brackets around the SERVICE_NAME was missing in the *tnsnames.ora* file.

```
<DBNAME> =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST = nupark-cnvr-ora )(PORT=1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
    (SERVER = DEDICATED)
    (SERVICE_NAME = <DBNAME> ***CLOSING ROUND BRACKET WAS MISSING HERE***
    )
  )

LISTENER_<DBNAME> =

  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = nupark-cnvr-ora)(PORT = 1521))
```

Answer (score 1):

I had just to replace my connection string

from:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
```

To:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this was caused by using a dynamic ipadress using installation. I reinstalled Oracle using a static ipadress and then everything was fine

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented below workaround to resolve this issue.

1. I have set the ORACLE_HOME using command prompt
   (right click cmd.exe and Run as System administrator).
2. Used below command

   `set oracle_home="path to the oracle home"`
3. Go to **All programs** --> **Oracle -ora home1** --> **Configuration migration tools** --> **Net Manager** --> **Listener**
4. Select Database Services from dropdown. 
   Both Global database name and SID are set to the same (ORCL in my case).
   Set Oracle Home Directory.

Oracle Net Manager window example from oracle documentation:
[image: Oracle Net Manager example]

5. Click on File and save network configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the VM worked for me

Answer (score 0):

My issue was resolved by replacing the'SID' in URL with 'service name' and correct host.

Answer (score 0):

`tnslsnr` is up but database is down.

For oracle novice it is not obvious that database may be down while connections are accepted.

I had to start up database manually like that

```
su - oracle
export ORACLE_SID=XE
sqlplus sys as sysdba
```

And then in sql console

```
startup
```

In my case i failed to startup but got another error message and found the source of a problem - i had to change host name and then database auto startup was functional again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my connection string url contained database name instead of SID.
Replacing database name with oracle database connection SID solved this problem.

To know your oracle SID's you can browse `tnsnames.ora` file.

`XE` was the actual SID, so this is how my tomcat connection string looks like now:

```
    <Resource
       name="jdbc/my_db_conn"
       auth="Container"
       type="javax.sql.DataSource"
       driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
       url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//127.0.0.1:1521/XE"
       username="test_user"
       password="test" />
```

My server version was "Oracle 11.2 Express", but solution should work on other versions too.

Answer (score 0):

I had a case that I used DBMS where I had to fulfill a db connection form.

I put SID into the Database field and in the dropdown, next to the field, I had had 'Service Name' value instead of 'SID' value.
(normally I don't use Oracle database so I've not been aware of the difference)

That was the reason I got the error message.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be in the incorrect URL.

For example, I'm using Oracle database (inside VM) with Spring framework and having this issue.

I had in my application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/orcl12c
```

But the db version was defferent:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/orclcdb
```

The correct URL can be found in the **tnsnames.ora** file (this file would be available where the Oracle server, so if you using VM, you should look for this file inside your host VM).
For example for Oracle in the VirtualBox the command to see this file is:

```
nano /u01/app/oracle/product/version/db_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case for **Linux** environment, the oracle file at `ORACLE_HOME/bin` was highlighted in "**Red**" color with different permissions as below:
[image]

I changed the permissions of this file as below:

**1)** Stop Oracle -> `sudo systemctl stop oracle.service`
**2)** Change the permission of oracle file at `ORACLE_HOME/bin` directory as "**sudo chmod 777 oracle**"
**3)** Start Oracle -> `sudo systemctl start oracle.service`

Then after this change, I checked the status of listener using **lsnrctl status**.Here, I can see the db instances loaded successfully.

However, I can connect using **sqldeveloper** only, with sqlplus command line I'm getting `ORA-12547: TNS Lost Contact` error. So, this can a quick **workaround** to use sqldeveloper.

**Note:** Take a backup of oracle file before changing the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky Oracle error, as it can have lots of possible causes.
It seems to mean that something in this chain of events is failing:

- Look up the service name in tnsnames.ora
- Connect to the host in the tnsnames entry
- Reach the listener on that host
- Tell the listener that you want to connect to the service specified in the tnsnames entry

Anything that throws that off can cause this error, from a missing bracket in tnsnames.ora, to a connecting to the wrong database host.

If **tnsping** works, that rules some things out, as it means that we can look up the entry in tnsnames, connect to the host, and contact the listener ... so we know, for instance, that the host at least exists, and there is an Oracle listener running there; but the listener is saying the service name is not known. That still leaves a lot of possibilities like:

- service name in tnsnames.ora is just wrong
- database instance is not running and/or not registered with the listener
- we're connecting to the wrong Oracle host
- we're connecting to the wrong listener (wrong port) on the correct Oracle host
- firewall/networking issue (apparently it's possible that a firewall could allow tnsping packets through but block other client applications from connecting)

I've seen an ORA-12514 with tiny typos in tnsnames.ora ... like incorrect indenting. But I suspect tnsping wouldn't succeed if that is the issue.

When I encountered this most recently, it was due to the 3rd bullet-point above; we were connecting to an Oracle database host -- just not the *right* host; we had to ensure that the hostname in the tnsnames entry was for the Oracle database server that was hosting this particular database service.

Connecting to the Oracle host and running `lsnrctl status` can help check that the service is known to this listener. Remember that `lsnrctl` by default checks the default listener name. You may need to check listener.ora to see if there are other names listeners in this database instance.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error in spring boot at first i gave the url as
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:TEST_DB

but give the url as

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/ORCL

this solved my problem

Comment: There are **30 existing answers** to this question, including a top-voted, accepted answer with nearly **three hundred votes**. Are you _certain_ your solution hasn't already been given? If not, why do you believe your approach improves upon the existing proposals, which have been validated by the community? Offering an explanation is _always_ useful on Stack Overflow, but it's _especially_ important where the question has been resolved to the satisfaction of both the OP and the community. Help readers out by explaining what your answer does different and when it might be preferred.