# oracle sql developer- ora-12514 error

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-12514

im using oracle sql developer to make my database, but now i stopped to work.
it wrote this:

> An error was encountered performing the requested operation:
>
> Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12514,
>   TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect
>   descriptor
>
> Vendor code 12514

i also tried to make new connection but it didnt help
pls help me,i dont know what to do, i need this to do my homework

when i tried to change connection it wrote this:

> An error was encountered performing the requested operation:
>
> ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
>   01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
>   *Cause:    An attempt was made to change the current username or password
>              without the appropriate privilege. This error also occurs if
>              attempting to install a database without the necessary operating
>              system privileges.
>              When Trusted Oracle is configure in DBMS MAC, this error may occur
>              if the user was granted the necessary privilege at a higher label
>              than the current login.
>   *Action:   Ask the database administrator to perform the operation or grant
>              the required privileges.
>              For Trusted Oracle users getting this error although granted the
>              the appropriate privilege at a higher label, ask the database
>              administrator to regrant the privilege at the appropriate label. Vendor code 1031

Answer (score 1):

Please check the services are running:
OracleOraDb11g_home1TNSListener and OracleServiceORCL.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to do some troubleshooting;  Here are a couple of suggestions:

- [ORA-12514 Tips](http://dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12514_tns_listener_does_not_currently_know_service_requested.htm)
- [ORA-12514 TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786782/ora-12514-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-service-requested-in-connect-d)
- [How to resolve error: ORA-12514](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/680942/how-to-resolve-error-ORA-TNS-listener-does-n)

Answer (score 0):

The service name ,you are using should be in sid column and not in service name entry box.
For example, the service name provided for you is overflow,you have to mention it in

ex:10.171.1.24:1521:overflow

Sid : overflow
Service : leave blank
Test the connection

Answer (score 0):

Go to Services
check whether the "ORACLEServiceORCL" is running or not.
if not running then right-click on it and click start.

Your problem may solve this.

[Happy coding :D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOeml.png)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me- Close your SQL Developer and launch again.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after restarting my PC and could not access my local database. This fixed it.

Go to Run > services.msc > Services (Local) > OracleService

Right-click on OracleService > Properties > Log On

Make sure Local System Account is checked then press OK.

Stop the OracleService and restart it. It should be working now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
Open SQL command line, connect to any schema, type:

```
select name from v$database;
```

It will show a name, if its orcl, then go back to SQL Developer,
click on plus sign, add database connection, select name as any name, database type oracle, authentication type default, username/password as known to you, go to service name, type orcl, and test. It will show success.

If by any reason you have forgot username password, then using sql command line, connect to sysdba. Type alter user sys identified by sys123. Go to SQL Developer, type sys and sys123 as username and password.

Enjoy!

Answer (score -1):

Mine was working fine till last night but this morning I found the said problem. I checked OracleOraDb11g_home1TNSListener and OracleServiceORCL was running and in "Started" status but still issue was there.

Just restarting both the services solved my issue. I suggest just try this once to save your time before exploring other solutions.