# java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error

Tags: java, database, oracle

We moved from the new server so basically I need to modify the connection string. But I am encountering this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
```

ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

IP Address = check
port = check
usermame - check
password = check

Where else do I need to modify?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error message is telling you there's a problem with the service/SID. Why don't you check that?

Comment: your IP address should be of format `...URL/DB_Name/` in case you only have it as `...URL/`

Comment: Yeah I've checked that. Is there any more configuration if you are using a service or SID?

Comment: Post the connection string.

Comment: May [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786782/ora-12514-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-service-requested-in-connect-d) can help you?

Comment: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//192.168.1.45:1521/EBCSDB - that is the connection string

Comment: @Jens Encountering table or view does not exists when I query select value from v$parameter where name='service_names'

Comment: @user3264438 It can not be. This is a [Oracle system table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/dynviews_2085.htm)

Comment: I may have no priviledge to select to system tables

Comment: Are you able to run `lsnrctl services` on the DB server? That would tell you which service names are registered. But how are you connecting to be able to (try to) query the parameter? What connection string are you using then?

Comment: I am connecting to the db using SID, so updated string : jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.45:1521:EBCSDB and is encountering new error

Comment: What new error? Has the SID and/or service name changed on the new server? We know nothing about why or how the DB moved; or even if it is actually running, it isn't entirely clear if your successful connections are to the old DB or the new DB.