# OCILOGON error ORA 12514

Tags: php, oracle

I am getting

```
Array (
       [code] => 12514     
       [message] => Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-12514     
       [offset] => 0     
       [sqltext] =>  
    )
```

when calling the `Ocilogon` function to connect with oracle. I got the correct string but still getting the error.

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786782/ora-12514-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-service-requested-in-connect-d) . You are getting this error, because the `SID` mentioned in your `connection string` is invalid.

Comment: @maheswaran Can you please elaborate this. I did not used SID as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ocilogon()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ocilogon.php) is deprecated (along with [many other aliases](http://php.net/manual/en/oldaliases.oci8.php)) and you should not be using it in new code.  Use [`oci_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php) instead.

Personally I use the following code that doesn't rely on environment settings like `TNS_ADMIN`:

```
oci_connect($username, $password, $conn_string);
```

Where `$conn_string` is a valid connection string that looks something like this:

```
(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = HOST.EXAMPLE.COM)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = EXAMPLE))
)
```

You can copy the connection string directly from your `TNSNAMES.ORA` file.

[This blog entry](https://blogs.oracle.com/alison/entry/oracle_database_connection_str) on oracle.com might be useful further reading for you.