# ORA-12514 error on **DBVisualizer**

Tags: database-connection, sqlexception, dbvisualizer

Please help with this error on **DBVisualizer**. No oracle or Sql is installed i just simply use **DBVisualizer**.

I have read lot of answers here on stackoverflow but not able to find a suitable answer.

**Note :** I used **Oracle Thin** Driver for connection.I have used latest updated version and also tried old version too.

```
An error occurred while establishing the connection:

Long Message:
Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Details:
   Type: java.sql.SQLException
   Error Code: 12514
   SQL State: 66000
```

[image]

Comment: Please try another DB Visualizer from https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/303bead8-003a-4e72-84af-5179d73ecc87 which I've written to work against any RDBMS or Flat file data source.  Works well with Oracle and would give you exact error details.

Comment: @Venkat I clicked on "Get Now" button on your link.I am not able to download.I tried after login also. no download link on your website too.

Comment: Thanks @PeacefulWarrior on notifying bad url.  I just corrected the link.  Please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me like the environment isn't set to the right path for oracle drivers to be found. Has this worked before? I ask because you say:

> "No oracle or Sql is installed"

Which is a little odd, in my opinion. Typically your environment must state "where to look" for db drivers.

Shot in the dark, but setting something like:
`TNS_ADMIN=/opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2` or `TNS_ADMIN=C:\path\to\oracle\thin\drivers` might work.

Next suggestion is to follow this and see if setting TNS_NAMES makes a difference:

[ORA-12514 TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786782/ora-12514-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-service-requested-in-connect-d)

Comment: Yes it used to work before. I don't know how it stopped working. yes may be issue with paths i guess.Let me try.

Answer (score 3):

What this error says is that the driver (which is btw properly loaded in DbVisualizer) is unable to establish connection with the database. There are tons of references to the "[listener does not currently know of service requested](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en#hl=en&q=%22listener%20does%20not%20currently%20know%20of%20service%20requested%22)" error message on the net.

In DbVisualizer I first suggest you change the **Connection Type** from **Service** to **SID** to see if that makes any difference. If neither of **Service** or **SID** works, does the server respond when you click the **Ping Server** button? If it doesn't you need to verify the listener settings in the Oracle server.

Comment: Yes i did that all. Even i was able to ping by clicking on "ping server" button.So i was confused.As of now i reinstalled everything and now its working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

in place of orcl give your database name...this should work the above error

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post;](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).