# How to Connect Airflow to oracle database

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, airflow

I am trying to create a connection to an oracle db instance (oracle:thin) using Airflow.

According to their [documentation](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:MCETp_jTg5oJ:https://github.com/airbnb/airflow/wiki/AirBnb-Airflow---Tips-and-Tricks-for-Oracle-Shops+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) I entered my hostname followed by port number and SID:

Host: example.com:1524/sid

filled other fields as:

**Conn Type**: Oracle

**Schema**: username ( [documentation](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:MCETp_jTg5oJ:https://github.com/airbnb/airflow/wiki/AirBnb-Airflow---Tips-and-Tricks-for-Oracle-Shops+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) says: use your username for schema )

**Login**: username

**Password**: * * *

[image: Create Connection Page -- Airflow]

After connection is setup, it gives the save error code for every query that I tried to execute (*ORA-12514*).
It seems like oracle doesn't let airflow to connect:

*ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor*

[image: ORA-12514]

Has someone experienced the same problem before. I mean connecting to a database shouldn't be a problem for a big platform like this. Or I am probably doing something wrong. Thanks

Version: Airflow v1.7.0,  Oracle11g

**EDIT:**

I am using the same hostname which I use in Oracle SQLDeveloper client:
[image: Oracle client connection configuration]

Comment: That usually indicates that either your connection is incorrect or that the listener on the DB is set up improperly.  Is your DB listener expecting a fully qualified name?

Comment: @TGray That is exactly the hostname that I use in Oracle SQLDelveloper (I added another screenshot form oracle client configuration).

Comment: I'm going to refer you to this answer on stackoverflow:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786782/ora-12514-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-service-requested-in-connect-d

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After digging into the source code, this is what finally how it worked for me:

Conn Type: Oracle

Host: example.com

schema: username

login: username

port: port number

extra: {"sid": "my sid", "dsn": "example.com"}

Comment: what is dsn - is it using ODBC type of connection? what about  connection using a service name?

Comment: your answer has "dsn" and not "dns". I know what dns is. My question was regarding airflow connectivity to an Oracle database. Oracle doesn't have "DSN", or "Data Source Name" term, it's an ODBC terminology. That's why I asked. Thanks.

Comment: nevermind.. got my questions answered looking at the source code pointed in the other response by @kavehmb

Comment: Perfect answer. I used to suck in the oracle connection for several days untill looking into the oracle hook source code. with extra sid, dsn setting. the connection work.  Poor doc for the hooks, perfect answer for stackoverflow.

Comment: damet garm, kheili mofid bood

Comment: @YongWang Can you please update how did you solve the problem with Oracle hook, I have the same issue but I don't understand what should I do?

Comment: I think two steps: first, you has to make sure you installed cx_oracle, and oracle_client lib; second, in the airflow oracle connection, apart from the normal input, you need input the json format config in extra inputblock like following:{ "dsn": "IP_or_Name" ,  "service_name": "your_service_name", 
   "encoding": "UTF-8"}

Answer (score 6):

You have a problem in your connection settings, either your setting is not loading  properly to the oracle hook or you are missing a python package that save/load your connection settings. You can test it by hard coding your credentials.

https://github.com/airbnb/airflow/blob/master/airflow/hooks/oracle_hook.py

```
conn = self.get_connection(self.oracle_conn_id)
dsn = conn.extra_dejson.get('dsn', None)
sid = conn.extra_dejson.get('sid', None)
service_name = conn.extra_dejson.get('service_name', None)
if dsn and sid and not service_name:
    dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(dsn, conn.port, sid)
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect(conn.login, conn.password, dsn=dsn)
elif dsn and service_name and not sid:
    dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(dsn, conn.port, service_name=service_name)
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect(conn.login, conn.password, dsn=dsn)
else:
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect(conn.login, conn.password, conn.host)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reference to the source code! It answered all the questions I had.

Comment: damet garm kaveh aziz, linkedin et roo dost dashti bezar connect shim :)

Answer (score 5):

for service name usage, if you leave (port, schema and extra) empty, you can put the full oracle connection descriptor under Host:

(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = mysidname)))

Answer (score 5):

this worked for me in extra field

```
{ "dsn":"192.168.x.x" , "service_name":"some.service.name" }
```

I get from https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/hooks/oracle_hook.py#L49

Comment: You should wrap your code snippet in backticks (`) to make it more readable.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone just does not see the connection in the **Ad hoc query dropdown** - you need to install the adapter: `pip install cx_Oracle` on the airflow server.

Comment: in my case numpy was missing, so `pip install numpy` solved the problem