# A database on apex.oracle.com is to be connected to airflow

Tags: oracle, airflow

I have database on apex.oracle.com and I want to make a connection to airflow.

This answer didnt help me: [How to Connect Airflow to oracle database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36945811/how-to-connect-airflow-to-oracle-database)

How to find the sid of my database?

I googled after alot of search I found a answer. Which was giving an error.

I executed this

```
grant select on v_$sql to username;
```

This gives an error:

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Please help me in complete detail if possible.

What should be entered in host name? I don't have any hosting platform. Should database need to be deployed or hostname can be found for a database created on apex.oracle

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell (which doesn't have to be correct), give up. Database on apex.oracle.com isn't accessible from the outer world. As stated,

> This site (apex.oracle.com) is intended only for the customer
>   evaluation of Oracle Application Express.

so - you should use it to test your Apex skills and nothing more. If you need to use a database, download and install your own copy - it is available on the Oracle Technology Network, free for evaluation purposes.

Or, consider contacting one of database hosting companies, if you want to access it on the Internet.