# Sql_alchemy_conn in Airflow cfg

Tags: oracle, airflow

I have to connect to remote oracle database and insert some rows into a table.Currently the airflow.cfg file in my home directory points to:  sqlite :///home/myuser/airflow.db

Could somebody please suggest if this needs to be changed to remote oracle database string and please suggest what to enter with any example,am not very sure

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No changing the sql_alchemy_conn line in the airflow.cfg only changes what airflow uses as its back end metadata store.

The standard way to connect to databases is to set up a "connection" then use them in your dags via hooks and operators.

I had a quick look around and it seems that oracle connections are a bit different to other sql databases and because I don't have access to an oracle databases to test I can't given you an example.

[This question shows an example of setting up a oracle connection.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36945811/how-to-connect-airflow-to-oracle-database)