# No connection to Oracle DB after Linux upgrade and OCI8-Installation

Tags: php, linux, oracle, apache, oracle-call-interface

OpenSuse Leap 42.1 (latest upgrade)
Apache2, PHP 5.5 installed
OCI8 installed
ORACLE 11g

Last week, I got some update issues with KDE and did an upgrade of OpenSuse Leap 42.1. I then went over the whole procedure of installing oci8 (as described in http://php.net/manual/en/oci8.installation.php and making sure to use the correct PECL) and everything worked fine.
But when I restarted my system a few hours later, I was't able to connect via hhtp to any vhost due to failed connection to the database.

I get no error logs anywhere, just a white 404 page or the message "Error: Could not connect to database. Aborting." (depending on which page I'm calling). Pages with no connection to the database work perfect!

SQLDeveloper connects without any proble, using the same parameters as in the config-files for the vhosts.

Anyone any idea?

Comment: have you tried going over the oci8 installation after the reboot ?

Comment: Yes, I did that. Seems I have some problems with the listener. After a bit of testing with very simple code I got an ORA-12514 error message. I think the oci-installation did some changes that came to effect AFTER the restart

Comment: but the listener is on the db server side.

Comment: did your client tnsnames.ora get mangled ?

Comment: or maybe the update changed something in the iptables configuration ?

Comment: Can you ping the server where the db is running ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem(s) solved!
as there were two different of them provoking a problem salad.

first, the update somehow managed to change some parameters in my config files, first of all the database name.

then, apache update from 2.2 to 2.4 DID change some things in the vhosts config files and therefore the errors were never logged in the former x_error.log and the 404 message was shown.

thx a lot for your response, louigi600!

Answer (score 0):

Generally when you get a

```
ORA-12514
```

it means that the listenr you are connecting to knows not the servicename/SID you're attempting to connect to. If you get that error it should indicate that the client got some sort of response from the listener which should exclude all sorts of network issues.
This is very much similar to [ORA-12514 TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10786782/6049292)
only that the issue sprouted up after an update.
I would first look in the client side tnsnames.ora and the server side listener.ora to check that everything is ok. Also check that the database is registered on the listener. Possibly also check that the db is remotely reachable from a known good client to exclude any issues on the listener configuration.