# ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor (oracle, C# VS2015)

Tags: c#, oracle11g

I'm trying to do a connection on C# with Oracle on Visual Studio 2015, and at first I had this error:

> ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor.

I don't have any idea what I do wrong.
Please help me

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-12514 TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786782/ora-12514-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-service-requested-in-connect-d)

Comment: Thx for help :)