# Cannot connect to newly created schema in Oracle18c. Giving Listener does not know of SID error

Tags: oracle, ora-12514

I am creating a new Schema in Oracle 18c. Schema is created successfully. But when i try to connect to this schema, i get an error saying:

> Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with
>   the following error: ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know
>   of service requested in connect descriptor

This is my listener.ora file:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = D:\Oracle18c)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:D:\Oracle18c\bin\oraclr18.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

Comment: *TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor:* What service did you request in the connect descriptor?

Comment: Also, a Listener error is not related to any schema. Can you connect to any other schemas in this database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-12514 TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786782/ora-12514-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-service-requested-in-connect-d)

Comment: Please update your opening post to include the following: 1) the output of 'lsnrctl status', as executed on the database server.  Also, what client program are you using, and how do you specify what database you are connecting to?