# Set Up a New Service in Oracle. Connecting locally works, but not remotely

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

First of all, I know almost nothing about Oracle, I'm just trying to connect to a database.  It's a pluggable database so I guess that can make it more challenging.  I'm trying to use Sql Server Migration Assistant (SSMA) and its Oracle connection still uses a SID.  It seems to me I need to set up a service, and then have that service act as a SID?  I stumbled onto https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln310924/how-to-connect-to-pluggable-databases-in-oracle-rac-12cr1?lang=en and managed to use `exec dbms_service` to create and start the service *mypdb_service*.  Then I updated my *tnsnames.ora* file on the server, adding this:
`MYPDB_SERVICE_PDB1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = MyServer.fo.fum)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = mypdb_service.fo.fum)
    )
  )`

I ran `lsnrctl reload` and now on the db server I can log in via sqlplus and reference the new service: `sqlplus System/MyPassword@MYPDB_SERVICE_PDB1`.  Works great, and I'm right in the PDB automatically.

From my PC I try to connect using SQL Developer, I put the new service name in the service name field and I get the error Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
`ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor` when trying to connect.

I am able to get to the **CBD** remotely, I just can't seem to set up a service to get directly to the **PDB**. If I set my session container to the PDB and run `SELECT NAME, PDB FROM all_services;` I see two rows, one for the servicename that I'm able to connect with (which drops me into the CBD) and one row for the new "direct to PDB" service I just created.  However, if I run `select value from v$parameter where name='service_names';` I only see the service name that drops me into the CBD.  All of this wouldn't be a problem if SSMA was more robust and didn't seem to need a SID to connect.  It also says it can connect via TNSNAMES but I haven't figured out how to do that in Windows either.

Comment: can you check if there is an entry for the new service in your local machine's tnsnames.ora

Comment: check this answer if it might help u https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786782/ora-12514-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-service-requested-in-connect-d/30861690#30861690

Comment: I don't have a tnsnames.ora file on my local machine, it's a Windows box.  Should I?