# Oracle Database can't connect in C# with error ORA-12514

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net

I am trying to connect an Oracle database to my C# project, but I am getting the following error:

> ORA-12514 TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in
>   connect descriptor

Screenshot:

[image]

I tested with the same values in Sql Developer and it was successful:

[image]

The only difference is that I am using SID instead of Service Name, so I tried to create two different connection strings to test it with SID and without it, and was still not able to connect:

```
string dt = "Data Source = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <IP>)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA = (SID = DB2DEV))); User Id = OMP; Password = <PW>; ";

OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(dt1);             

if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
{
  labelteste.Text = "Not Opened";
}
else
{
  labelteste.Text = "Open";               
}
```

I used the `if` condition above to validate if the connection was opened, and it always returned `Not Opened`.

Does anyone have any idea why is this happening?

Comment: _"I used the if condition above to validate if the connection was opened, and it always returned Not Opened.")_  ...that's not related to your connection string. It's simlply because you haven't opened it. Just creating an OracleConnection object doesn't open the connection automatically, it just sets up the object. You have to call `conn.Open();` yourself. Also it's normally better to utilise a `using` block to ensure your object is disposed properly after use. See example at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnection.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: SQL Developer is Java based and uses JDBC driver which is completely different to connection in .NET. Using the connection wizard is also different to writing the connectionString by yourself.

Comment: See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786782/ora-12514-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-service-requested-in-connect-d

Answer (score 0):

SID and SERVICE_NAME are entirely different. On the DB server, use the "lsnrctl status" command or "lsnrctl services" to get a listing of all registered service names for the database, then use one of those in your connect string.