# Unable to connect to DB from Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle21c

I am trying to configure a database in Oracle SQL Developer, database is Oracle 21c. Upon initial troubleshooting it seems to be an issue with the listeners. Below are some more details that will help for troubleshooting.
When I try to check status of listener in cmd (admin mode), I get below error:

```
C:\Windows\System32>lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on 18-NOV-2022 20:24:49

Copyright (c) 1991, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.1.207)(PORT=1521)))
TNS-12535: TNS:operation timed out
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00505: Operation timed out
   64-bit Windows Error: 60: Unknown error
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   64-bit Windows Error: 2: No such file or directory
```

and when I try to start listener, I get below error :

```
C:\Windows\System32>lsnrctl start

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on 18-NOV-2022 20:26:01

Copyright (c) 1991, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
System parameter file is C:\app\patil\product\21c\homes\OraDB21Home1\network\admin\listener.ora
Log messages written to C:\app\patil\product\21c\diag\tnslsnr\Nisarg\listener\alert\log.xml
Error listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.1.207)(PORT=1521)))
TNS-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00515: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
   64-bit Windows Error: 49: Unknown error

Listener failed to start. See the error message(s) above...
```

Below is the error we get when we try to connect from Oracle SQL Developer :

[image]

There is no problem with the service, screenshot below :
[image]

Below thing also helps to confirm that there is no issue with the DB :

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.819]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\patil>sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Fri Nov 18 20:37:34 2022
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 21.3.0.0.0

SQL> select name, open_mode from v$pdbs;

NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OPEN_MODE
----------
PDB$SEED
READ ONLY

XEPDB1
READ WRITE


SQL>
```

Comment: are you sure of the ip configured for the listener(192.168.1.207)?

Comment: I tried multiple things to test and might would have end up with this IP, what should be a default IP in here?

Comment: But I was able to connect with the same IP some days back

Comment: the ip is that of your system (where the db is running). If you're using dhcp, then the ip might change between reboots.

Comment: You are right, after reboot the IP got changed, but now I am getting another error, will post it in a while

Comment: Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
  (CONNECTION_ID=Bin0KBHhTBq1jeApVQJa9Q==)

Comment: Used this link for future troubleshooting 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41224966/7088682

Comment: Thanks @gsalem , Any way you know to make this IP thing dynamic? –

Comment: Use hostname and not ip. Be sure to sue the proper service name, not SID nor pdbname when you try to connect.