# A connection error while connecting oracle-xe in docker with Oracle SQL developer

Tags: oracle, docker

I have successfully created the database container and saved it in somewhere of my computer, and successfully connected the database in container with the Oracle SQL Developer. However, while I restart my computer, rerun the database in container, I failed to connect the database using the Oracle Sql Developer and it gave me the error that shown in the picture below. If doing another connection, it gave me the similar error message.[image: error message]

So I do not know how to handle this kind of problem. Should I delete the container and do it again?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ORA-12514 TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786782/ora-12514-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-service-requested-in-connect-d)